# Integrate Silverlight Unit Testing with Visual Studio 2008 Test Results Panel?

Tags: unit-testing, silverlight, visual-studio-2008, tdd

I would like to run my Silverlight Unit Tests from Visual Studio instead of opening a new instance of my Silverlight Test App in the browser.

Apparently it is possible (http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/09/rc0-new-test-features/ - search for "Visual Studio Team Test log provider output")....but I don't understand how you enable this, does anyone know how?

Would be great if these tests would run from the "Run All Tests in Solution" button (Ctrl+R, A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post you referenced clearly states that this is output only and does not integrate Silverlight UT with Visual Studio Team Testing System. It will simply output into a TRX format that can then be opened in that window within Visual Studio. You still cannot run your Silverlight tests from a vsmdi, you will need to run them from within the web browser test harness.

I agree it would be great if the tests would run from the "Run All Tests in Solution" button, but that is not possible with the current tools today.

Answer (score 0):

I have [written a blog post](http://flatlinerdoa.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!17124D03A9A052B0!629.entry) about how to get the Silverlight Testing Framework to output the Visual Studio "TestResults.trx" log files. I couldn't find anything about how to do this anywhere else.